# Can EF's MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion downgrade if the model is "behind" the db?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I put

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, MyConfiguration>());
```

in my `Application_Start` because I want my db to automatically become "synced" with my model when the site starts.

I've been doing some testing and I found out that it works when I have

```
model: A -> B -> C
   db: A -> B
```

but not

```
model: A -> B
   db: A -> B -> C
```

The second case represents a situation where I redeploy after removing problematic migration `C` from the code and expect that it would downgrade to `B`. Does EF have some flag I can specify that makes this happen?

Comment: The clue is in the title, it will migrate to the latest version. Think about it this way, if your code doesn't know about migration C, it has no way to roll it back.